# create table but first finding the last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project where I pull excel data into my spreadsheet with copy and paste. I then have to create charts for each category which varies anywhere from two columns to 25 columns. In creating the charts I make a "Table" of the data. Because the number of columns can vastly vary I am trying to use end.(xltoleft) reading that address. For some reason, I can not add the string in the ListObjects.add(xlSrcRange. I get Method Range of object _Global failed.

```
 last_column = Worksheets("SelectFile").Cells(33, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim LastCol As String
    LastCol = Range("BA33").End(xlToLeft).Address
    Range("A34").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$33:&LastCol"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-51
```

Comment: Range("$A$33:&lc") is the problem

Comment: Variables don't belong inside quotes. Plus you have `last_column` and `LastCol`, yet are trying to use `lc`.

Comment: What is should look like is Range("$A$33:$AA$33") but "AA33 is variable depending on the data loaded. So I created LastCol which is a address of the last column but I cant put that in Range.

Comment: My mistake it is suppose to be lastcol. I have both last_coulmn which is cell number and LastCol which is Address. I have tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is how your Range reference is written.

Currently you have `Range("$A$33:&LastCol")` which is literally `Range("$A$33:&LastCol")`.

Move the quotes like so: `Range("$A$33:" & LastCol)`

The cell reference is enclosed in quotes as a string up until the colon and then concatenated with your `LastCol` variable.

If your variable `LastCol` represents say, Cell address `$AA$33`, the above example would translate to `Range("!$A$33:$AA$33")`.

If you put a variable enclosed in quotes like so: `"$A$33:&LastCol"`, your not  referencing the variable as it becomes part of a string. To concatenate correctly (using `&`) you need to ensure it's outside of the double quotes like so: `"$A$33:" & LastCol`. That basically translates to joining a string `"$A$33:"` with your variable value `"$AA$33"` (per the example I've given above).

Comment: Thanks to both BigBen and Samuel Everson. I have corrected and found it working.